# My generated js file from typescript are not used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2019

Using Typescript and React on Visual Studio 2019, I compile correctly the say "ClientApp\Components\a.js" file when saving the corresponding "ClientApp\Components\a.tsx" file, but when I launch the Visual Studio debugger, the javascript source is taken from the folder wwwRoot/Dist/Main.js, and not from my a.js file. So it seems that the Main.js file is a concatenation of all the *.tsx files.

On the Project Properties, I check "Compile on Save" (which is what I want).

Comment: Are you using webpack or any other bundle/module solution?

Comment: @Marcello: Yes I am using webpack and thats certainly why I had problem when I dropped my tsconfig.json file. Now I can rollback and reinstall tsconfig.json or I can  keep the Visual Studio Typescript config and remove  Webpack which is not so useful for my very small project.

Comment: Even for simple project you need webpack if you are using js libraries. If you decide to keep webpack, you should keep vs from compiling typescript files by adding `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` on `<PropertyGroup>`

Comment: In fact I have already this line in my project file. I have deleted my dist folder, and it was rebuilt with fresh and updated source. But still, when I save atsx file, I can see something is happening (a background task is started) but I cannot see any trace, and my main.js file is still not updated